# Replication of multiple masters to a single slave server

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I am running MySQL 5.1.36 in all my servers.

I want to replicate database_A from master_host_A and database_B from master_host_B into 
a single slave server. All the three MySQL servers are remotely located.

Is it possible for me to setup replication of multiple masters to a single slave server ?
If yes please let me know how should I approach?

Is it feasible for production servers ?

Warm Regards

Supratik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not support replicating from multiple masters to a single slave.

If you want to replicate data from multiple masters to a single physical server, you will need multiple instances of MySQL slaving from the different masters.  If listening on TCP/IP, you will need to configure them on different ports and specify different locations.